# Can a pdf store meta-information (e.g. name of the program with which it was created)?

Tags: pdf, editors, metadata

This is not a tex question per se, but I think it is not totally off-topic either.
I heard a while ago, that when one creates a pdf, besides its content a pdf can also store some meta-information (for example the name of the user that created the pdf, the program with which it was created etc.), similar to ID3-tags (I believe they're called).

Is this true ?

If yes, is there any way to edit this information ?

EDIT: I'm sorry, my explanation weren't good. I meant editing the pdf **without** having its source tex fil (so using hyperref won't apply).

Comment: Setting metadata outside of a TeX run is off-topic for us, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to set the information also without `hyperref` (but notice that when this package is used, the following method must *not* be used):

```
\pdfinfo{
  /Title (example.pdf)
  /Creator (TeX)
  /Producer (pdfTeX 1.40.12)
  /Author (Tom and Jerry)
  /CreationDate (D:20061226154343+01’00’)
  /ModDate (D:20061226155343+01’00’)
  /Subject (Example)
  /Keywords (mouse, cat) }
```

(taken from the documentation of pdfTeX). It's not necessary to set all the fields.

Answer (score 4):

with `hyperref` you can write some informations into the pdf:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle=foo,
  pdfauthor=me,
  pdfsubject=bar,
  pdfkeywords={foo bar baz}
}

\begin{document}

foo
\end{document}
```

Also possible:

```
\usepackage[pdfinfo={author=me,title=...,...}]{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can use `\pdfinfo`, or the `hyperref` package.

Alternatively, you can use the [`xmpincl`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/xmpincl.html) package. I am not sure whether `hyperref` dominates `xmpincl` or vice versa concerning features and functionality. At least it is possible to specify a license and such with `xmpincl`, which will get its own tab in the pdf metadata.